# How to run Promise on a function that repeats itself?

Tags: javascript, jsx, es6-promise, stenciljs

I have following function inside a Stencil component that repeats itself until a menu is built.

When I wrap the function in a Promise I get an error inside my Stencil component:

```js
renderMenu(obj, type, mobile) {

    let thisNested = this;

    return new Promise(function () {

      function checkMobile() {
        if (mobile) {
          return 'harmoni-navigation--' + type + '' + ' ' + 'harmoni-navigation--mobile';
        } else {
          return 'harmoni-navigation--' + type + '';
        }
      }

      return <div class={checkMobile()}>
        <ul>
          {
            Object.values(obj).map((object) => {
              return <li
                class={object['harmoniChildren']

                  /** Check if menu has any children. */

                  ? 'harmoni-navigation__item--' + type + '' + ' ' + 'harmoni-navigation__item--has-child'
                  : 'harmoni-navigation__item--' + type + ''}>

                <a href={object['url']}>
                  {object['title']}
                </a>

                {object['harmoniChildren'] && !mobile &&
                thisNested.renderMenu(object['harmoniChildren'], 'child', false)}

                {object['harmoniChildren'] && mobile &&
                thisNested.renderMenu(object['harmoniChildren'], 'child', true)}
              </li>
            })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    })
  }
```

The error is specific to StencilJS: *vNode passed as children has unexpected type.
Make sure it's using the correct h() function.
Empty objects can also be the cause, look for JSX comments that became objects.*

However, I think the problem lies somewhere within my code, as I have never used Promises before.

Hope someone can help!

Thanks!

Comment: And why do you need the promise?

Comment: React is probably expecting the function to return JSX, and returning a promise breaks it.

Comment: I need to run a Popper.js Initialisation, that only works once all items have been rendered.

Answer (score 0):

The renderer function can't be asynchronous for various reasons, so you also can't await async functions/methods within your `render` method. Stencil allows you to set various life-cycle methods on your component (see [component lifecycle docs](https://stenciljs.com/docs/component-lifecycle)) and all of these methods can be async. The idea is that you use a method like `componentWillLoad` or `componentDidLoad` to prepare the state of your component asynchronously.

In the code that you have posted you're definitely not using the Promise API properly because the function you're passing into `new Promise()` receives two callbacks `resolve` and `reject` of which you should at least use the former (otherwise your promise will never be fulfilled). There's many guides on promises that you can read (maybe try https://www.promisejs.org for a start).

Nothing in your `renderMenu` function needs async behavior so I'm not totally sure what you're trying to achieve with that promise anyway. Since you've mentioned in the comments that you want to do an initialization of a library after your component has rendered, I suggest that you try the `componentDidLoad` method which is executed after your component has rendered.

BTW the error you're encountering is indeed caused by your code, because a promise is not something that Stencil knows how to render.